# How to re-deploy Reactjs App to github pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I followed the instructions on [this site](https://reactgo.com/deploy-react-app-github-pages/) to deploy my reactjs App to Github Pages.

And It works well but I have some problem with re-deploy the app When the source code are change.

It seems that I have to commit gh-pages branch but I usually commit to master branch and when I commit to master branch, nothing happens in Github Pages.

So I thought if I just type `npm run deploy` in console it will works, but it's not.

And I found the solution that Remove gh-pages branch and deploy again and it works. But I want to find easier solution to re-deploy my reactjs app to github.

Is there any another solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have to remove previous gh-pages branch. Only things that I have to do is just enter command `npm rum deploy` again and wait.